# How Pandas DataFrame work with comparison operator?

Tags: python, pandas

Why `df>0` returns another DataFrame? Is this "operator overload"? (maybe I used the wrong term)

How is it implemented under the hood?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why `df > 0` returns another DataFrame?

It performs the comparison elementwise, so the result is a data frame of boolean values. This behavior is useful in conjunction with the subscript operator, allowing for easy and readable data filters:

```
positiveDf = df[df > 0]
```

> Is this "operator overload"? (maybe I used the wrong term)

Yes, this is an example of overloaded operators. The term is right.

> How is it implemented under the hood?

This operator uses the generic [`pandas.DataFrame.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) function. I'm not sure how this function is implemented, but I guess it calls native code at some point.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much!